# Postgresql 13 LOG: could not rename file "pg_wal/0000000100000001000000C6"

Tags: postgresql

Something very strange appear in my postgresql log file. I updated postgresql version from 13.0 to 13.1 and it's the same thing:

```
2020-12-21 15:17:55.652 EET [4316] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

2020-12-21 15:17:55.657 EET [4316] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432

2020-12-21 15:17:55.660 EET [4316] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432

2020-12-21 15:17:55.998 EET [5224] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-12-21 15:17:01 EET

2020-12-21 15:17:56.075 EET [4316] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

2020-12-21 16:43:14.938 EET [7832] LOG:  could not rename file "pg_wal/0000000100000001000000C6": Permission denied

2020-12-21 16:48:17.949 EET [7832] LOG:  could not rename file "pg_wal/0000000100000001000000C6": Permission denied

2020-12-21 16:53:15.911 EET [7832] LOG:  could not rename file "pg_wal/0000000100000001000000C6": Permission denied

2020-12-21 16:58:14.865 EET [7832] LOG:  could not rename file "pg_wal/0000000100000001000000C6": Permission denied

2020-12-21 17:03:14.730 EET [7832] LOG:  could not rename file "pg_wal/0000000100000001000000C6": Permission denied
```

Can't find anything about that message. After restarting the service and after some time that message starts showing on every 5 minutes. I know that is because of `checkpoint_timeout = 5min` but that is all I know. Someone to help me?

Answer (score 1):

It could be somebody or something locked or modified the permissions on this file. Perhaps it was anti-virus software (which should always be prevented from messing with the data directory).

But there is also a [bug in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/YFBcRbnBiPdGZvfW%40paquier.xyz) that causes this problem. This bug has been fixed with commit [909b449e00fc](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=909b449e00fc2f71e1a38569bbddbb6457d28485) in PostgreSQL 13.3 and v14 or better (the bug was introduced in v13).

Comment: Yeah I think about that, but why is that happening after let's say 1 hour from starting the service? That is strange..

Comment: Perhaps that is when the anti-virus software decided it was time to scan the files?

Comment: I am tracing the activity on pg_wal folder and there is no alien in it :D Postgresql deleted the file (no idea why, what I read in postgre manual is that it just rename the files) at some time. And after that when the checkpoint_timeout comes then the message is created in the log.

Comment: The error says "permission denied", not "no such file or directory".

Comment: I have revisited that and added a link to a live PostgreSQL bug with the same symptoms.

Comment: I have the same instance. I had a doubt on antivirus, but even inactivating the antivirus, the same happening!. is there any solution now? I'm using version 13

Comment: @Sajeev This has been fixed in the meantime, see the updated answer.